# Setting Reminders/Alarms in iOS8-iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, alarm, eventkit

**Main question:** Should I be using local notifications, alarms, or reminders if I want attach due dates to tasks in my app? I want them to get a notification even if the app isn't running when the deadline arrives.

I found [this](http://stunningco.de/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/) tutorial on using UILocalNotification which it says can:

> gives us the ability to cast notifications to a user without running the application

However, it was written six years ago and also states that this was introduced in iOS4. I know that a lot changes over 5 iOS versions.

I also [read](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), alternatively, that I could use Event Kit. However, that seems more complicated than UILocalNotification.

Lastly, I could use probably take the current date/time and reminder date/time and [create a timer](http://makeapppie.com/2015/04/24/swift-swift-using-nstimer-to-make-a-timer-or-alarm/) to countdown.

So if I just want to attach due dates to tasks in my app (they don't need to show up in reminders or in the calendar), what's the best method and why?

Comment: Yes you should use `UILocalNotification`.

Comment: You have to use UILocalNotification.

Comment: Thank you both. Since the tutorial I found is in objective-C, if either of you wants to provide an example of creating a UILocalNotification in **Swift**, I could mark it as the correct answer. Or maybe an answer distinguishing the differences between UILocalNotification uses and alarm uses, that'd work too. - @rptwsthi

Answer (score 1):

I found following chunk of [code here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/). This is also a good tutorial for how to create event in application.

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Todo Item \"\(item.title)\" Is Overdue" // text that will be displayed in the notification
notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
notification.fireDate = item.deadline // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
notification.userInfo = ["UUID": item.UUID, ] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
notification.category = "TODO_CATEGORY"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```